# Python programming reading data

Tags: python

```
count = 0
for row in file:
    count+=1
    segment = row[:-1].split(", ")
    num += 1
    if segment[14] == '>50K':
        count1 += 1
        print ("no of line are", count1)
    elif segment[14] == '<=50K':
        count2 += 1
        print ("no of line are", count2)
```

so this code works but if I comment out both of the print statements my code kinda gives me this error

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

can someone explain to my why and how to fix this as i'm really confused.

Comment: The full traceback shows you where exactly the error occurs. That would be helpful to know.

Answer (score 3):

Ponder on this koan:

```
segment = "".split()   # returns []
s = segment[14]
```

*... what is the sound of accessing a list item that is not there?*

Answer (score 1):

Probably the error happens where you try to access `segment[14]`.

On a line which has less than 15 segments, you simply cannot access `[14]`.

You might want to check `len(segments)` before, or you might want to catch this exception and deal with it appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

Another problem with the code: you are not defining count1 and count2, just like you set count to 0 in the first line.